# Show directive as result of a click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to show content that comes from a directive when the user clicks on a link.

```html
<li><a href="#" ng-click="directive_here">Show popup</a></li>
```

Obviously I'm new to angularjs.  I know the approach above doesn't make sense really but I was also trying to imagine how this might be done with ng-if but not coming up with anything.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Edit 1: The directive that I want to use is:

```
<ng-pop-up></ng-pop-up>
```

That's part of ngPopup.

Edit 2: This is now resolved.  It turns out that in the case of ngPopup, you put the directive somewhere, then you open the dialog using the open method, so I really didn't take advantage of the solutions given here.  Giving Martin credit because his solution solves problem originally stated.  Thanks all.

Comment: I think I can solve this with the information given.  My remaining issue is I'm having trouble getting the basic ng-pop-up working but I will figure this out myself and report back here once I solve it.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for.

1. When you say, `content from a directive`, is this an existing directive, or do you think the content should come from a directive?
2. In your example where you have `show popup`, do you mean you would like to have a dialog displayed when you click the link?
3. Or do you just want something like the following example?

```js
angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app=app>

  <a href="#" ng-click='showMessage = true'>Click Here</a>
  <div ng-show="showMessage">Your Message Here</div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at using `ng-if` ([AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)).  You can use a boolean in your scope to that is toggled by the `ng-click`.